# Can someone please assist with a JS function for var length

Tags: javascript

i am trying to display a modal based on a number of matched cards in a memory game.

i have already set var to be

```
let matchedCards = document.querySelectorAll('.match');
```

and then checking if `matchedCards.length == 4` display a a modal (function) but I am unable to even enter that function for some reason.

```
// function to intialise game
function initGame() {
    //set initial timer value
    timer.innerHTML = '0 mins 0 secs';
    //set initial star rating
    for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
        stars[i].style.color = "#FFD700";
        stars[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    //deck selection and populating with generated card
    let deck = document.querySelector('.deck');
    let cardHTML = shuffle(cards).map(function(card) {
        return generatedCard(card);
    });
    deck.innerHTML = cardHTML.join('');
    allCards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
    //card function
    allCards.forEach(function(card) {
        card.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            openCards.push(card);
            card.classList.add('open', 'show', 'disabled');
            // setting move counter and matched/unmatched cards
            if (openCards.length === 2) {
                movesCounter();
                if (openCards[0].dataset.card === openCards[1].dataset.card) {
                    matched();
                } else {
                    unmatched();
                }
            } else {
                allMatched();
            }
        })
    });
};

//function for all matched
function allMatched() {
    let matchedCards = document.querySelectorAll('.match');
    if (matchedCards.length === 4) {
        console.log(fourcards);
        congratulations();
    }
}

// match the 2 cards that are open if they are of the same type
function matched() {
    openCards[0].classList.add("match", "disabled");
    openCards[1].classList.add("match", "disabled");
    openCards = [];
}
```

expecting to see the congrats modal popup if there are 4 matched cards on the deck.

Comment: I imagine the modal is displayed in the `congratulations` function. Can we see it?

Comment: Ok. You definitely should add that to the question, along with your HTML structure.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to this, just added the congrats function to the code

Comment: Where are you checking if `matchedCards == 4`? I see `if (matchedCards.length >= 2)`.

Comment: Edited, i was debugging with 2 or more.

Comment: Are you seeing the result of `console.log(fourcards)`?

Comment: No i am not seeing "fourcards" in the console.

Comment: Then either the length of `.matched` is not 4, or `openCards.length` is 2.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] so we can see what's going on?

Comment: When i type in `document.querySelectorAll('.match');` in the console, it's returning


`NodeList(4) [li.card.open.show.disabled.match, li.card.open.show.disabled.match, li.card.open.show.disabled.match, li.card.open.show.disabled.match]
0: li.card.open.show.disabled.match
1: li.card.open.show.disabled.match
2: li.card.open.show.disabled.match
3: li.card.open.show.disabled.match
length: 4`

Comment: Are you sure you're getting into the `allMatched()` function in the first place? The browser has a powerful debugger, you can set breakpoints, single-step through it, etc. so you can trace exactly what's happening.

Comment: I'd recommend putting all your code in a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see what's actually happening.  We can't see the HTML and a lot of functions you're calling, and this kind of drawn out discussion rarely helps.

Comment: I have added my code here - https://codepen.io/slipknut/pen/eYOamvP

Comment: Hi all, i have fixed the issue by moving the allMatched() into the main If condition.